# Many to many fails with Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have three tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag` (
    `id`  INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tag` VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entry` (
    `id`      INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`    VARCHAR(511) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `entry_tag_list` (
    `entry_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `tag_id`    INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`, `tag_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `entry_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`entry_id`)
    REFERENCES `entry` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `tag_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`)
    REFERENCES `tag` (`id`)
);
```

And `Entry` and `Tag` objects.
Entry contains a list of tags annotated in the following manner

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "entry_tag_list", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)})
private List<Tag> tags;
```

But whenever I try to run the code and perform a simple get, I get an error saying

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'tags2_.tags_id' in 'on clause'
```

It literally happens when I do

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(aClass).list();
```

Unfortunately I have no means of renaming the column names for tag and entry from being `id`, thus I couldn't follow any examples posted online.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error mentions a column `tags_id` that it doesn't know, but your table has `tag_id`. I notice you don't declare `name="tag_id"` in your JoinTable. I'm not a Hibernate user, but don't you need to tell it which column in the join table references each of your primary tables? That's what I see in an example like in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will start with this error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'tags2_.tags_id' in 'on clause'
```

So hibernate is searching for **tags_id** inside **entry_tag_list** but as per your Mysql mapping it's **tag_id**.

Now when I see your **ManyToMany** configuration I don't see any name defined for tag_id

So this line is creating problem

```
private List<Tag> tags;
```

What Hibernate is doing is taking **variable Name and appending "_id" to it** as you have not defined.

So either you add a **name** to refer to or change List variable to

```
private List<Tag> tag;
```